# Currency textbox in ASP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I tried the Masked Edit from the AJAX Toolkit Extender but it doesn't do what I need to do.  Its too clumsy and it also breaks a small script I run that calculates the textboxes automatically. One of the textboxes (total) is data bound and there's a second one where the user inputs an amount and I need to force it so its in currency format (only two decimals, $ sign). I tried with a range validator but I would then also limit the amounts to whatever number I input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use RegularExpression validator, here is a regex from regexlib.com for currency validation.

```
^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$
```

Comment: That code in a way works. Is there a way I can limit decimal spaces to only two?

Comment: sorry, I am regex challenged ;) maybe you can find something on regexlib.com or try to ask another question here on SO

Comment: Hahaha, actually this works quite well. I will just limit the textbox with some javascript, thanks a lot Antonio. And yes, Regex is pretty annoying to work with.

Comment: actually you can replace all `[0-9]`s with `\d`.